# Font Awesome version 4 - Button with spin icon

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I found this great JSFiddle using *Bootstrap* and *Font Awesome* to show a spinner inside a button:
[JSFiddle snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/AndrewDryga/zcX4h/1/)

```
<button class="btn btn-success has-spinner">
    <span class="spinner"><i class="icon-spin icon-refresh"></i></span>
    Foo
</button>
```

[image: Spin icon in button]

This was using *Font Awesome* version 3.0.2. I'm using version 4.2.0, but is it right that this has been removed from the new version? I cannot find the *icon-spin* CSS class. How can I do this in the new version?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some things changed between 3.x and 4.x. Have a look at this snippet:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<button>
  <i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i> Foo
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Most (maybe all) icon names and actions are changes between v3.2.0 and v4.2.0.

the spinner for example is called "fa-spin"

Check it out on their website:
http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/#spinner